Non-bold diacritics over bold math symbols with correct alignment - packages "bm" and "accents" incompatible?
I want to use non-bold diacritics on bold math symbols. For correct alignment I need to use the package bm. But I also need to import the package accents for other reasons. This seems to undo the alignment fixing.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
    \tilde f \;
    \tilde{\bm f} \;
    \bm{{\tilde f}}
\]

\end{document}

This results in the following (same as without bm package, using \boldsymbol instead):

Either the diacritic is bold (right), or not properly aligned (middle).
How can I fix this?
I am aware of this question. The answerer seems to not notice the problem of wrong alignment.

In an ideal world it would just work out of the box, but

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\[
    \tilde f \;
    \tilde{\bm f} \;
    \,\tilde{\!\bm f} \;
    \bm{{\tilde f}}
\]

\end{document}


I was mostly wondering whether there is a way to solve the problem systematically. Do you say there might be no other way than to hack it?

@M.Winter well it's tricky latex defines math accents, amsmath redefines them, accent package redefines them again and they all have more issues than you might hope, so it's always possible, eg you could define \tilde to check if its argument is \bm f and if so add the spacing otherwise do the original definition, but expanding that to all possible arguments that need adjustment gets hard, and if you change the document font the inserted spaces might need adjustment again, so I'd be tempted to hack it as above....

Thanks for your explanation! :)
